# Unable to hiding error messages

Tags: php

How to hide error's such like this

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\\') as previousid,
(SELECT IFNULL(min(id),-1) FROM bikes WHERE' at line 2
```

I have put `off` on `display_errors = Off` and `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`
Also doesn't matter if I put `error_reporting(0);` on top of my code or `@` before the query. The error is always showed.

edit:

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT *,
            (SELECT IFNULL(max(id),-1) FROM bikes WHERE `id` < '.($currentId).') as previousid,
            (SELECT IFNULL(min(id),-1) FROM bikes WHERE `id` > '.($currentId).') as nextid
                FROM bikes WHERE `id` = ' . ($currentId)))
```

and if I try on URL lets say `bikes.php?id='` or other to sql inject I get this on my page.

**The query work normaly and this is when I try to manipulate(sql inject) in URL. Then it's shown this and I want to hide it. I don't want to show info for my tables.. etc.**

Comment: Well, the most efficient way of hiding the error would be by fixing it!

Comment: This is when I try to simulate sql inject in the URL..

Comment: show us your php code where you are querying this

Comment: I edited my question with the query

Comment: @Pankucins, I'm not sure what to fix when it's working normaly.

Comment: Looks like $currentId has rubbish in it. Also why do you have parenthasis arount each reference to $currentId

Comment: Have you restarted apache after the change? Also make sure you are updating the right php.ini file.

Comment: I have 2x php.ini and changed setings in both. Also I restart apache. Other querys in other pages don't have this problem but only this query has it..

Answer (score 0):

your error seems to come from your sql query.Try this:

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT *,
            (SELECT IFNULL(max(id),-1) FROM `bikes` WHERE `id` < '.$currentId.') as previousid,
            (SELECT IFNULL(min(id),-1) FROM `bikes` WHERE `id` > '.$currentId.') as nextid
                FROM bikes WHERE `id` = ' . $currentId))
```

Comment: Same, when I put in URL `bikes.php?='"` I can see it again - `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'\") as previousid, (SELECT IFNULL(min(id),-1) FROM `bikes` WHERE `' at line 2`

Comment: you should fix that error,not ignore it.It's a syntax error.Try what I wrote in my answer

Comment: This is what I get with your query. Same as mine.

Comment: do you use phpmyadmin?try and execute my query there and see if you get that error

Comment: May be I can't write it properly in phpmyadmin but I try few times and always get this `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT IFNULL(max(id),-1) FROM `bikes` WHERE `id` < '.$currentId.') as previousi' at line 1`

Comment: replace $currentId with a number in phpmyadmin...application doesn't know who is $currentId.